# Have Travis to modify/add commits to a PR

Tags: travis-ci

I have a C++ Github project and I would like to:

- lower the boundary for people to contribute, but
- keep the clang-format styling enforced

I am wondering if there is a way for me to have Travis to automatically apply (formatting) changes to people's PR. Looks like this is technically possible according to [these github](https://help.github.com/articles/allowing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork/) [help pages](https://help.github.com/articles/committing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork/), but I cannot find an example.

Has anyone ever tried this and could give me pointers? Or is there any project that already does this?